# Bootstrap material design- floating labels are not floated when data is loaded dynamically

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, material-design, bootstrap-material-design

I am using bootstrap material design for my angular app. Everything works fine except when I change the models associated with inputs (floating label inputs) programmatically after the page has been loaded, the floating labels are not floated.

[image: FLoatinglabel issue]

Answer (score 4):

You must fire a `change` event when you change the value programmatically.

Comment: A clean way to do it is changing ng-model directive as proposed in [this comment](https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design/issues/148#issuecomment-150169488) by [Josephdias92](https://github.com/Josephdias92) at github.

Comment: Yes actually if someone wants to use a framework like Angular, React or so on should avoid to use the built-in JS and write its own components

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular2 then no custom directive is needed.  On the label do something like this.

```
<label [class.active]="name && name.length > 0">Some Label</label>
```