# Jquery .val() dont work properly with Material Design Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-material-design

I'm using Material Design Bootstrap to style and do something nice with the inputs placeholder.

```
<input id="ConfigName" class="form-control floating-label" placeholder="Name" type="text">
```

But if I try to add/change some text to the input with jquery it doesn't work correctly.

```
$('#ConfigName').html("testersres"); // dont work
$('#ConfigName').text("testersres"); // dont work
$('#ConfigName').val("testersres"); //Placeholder and "testersres" is placed on top of each other
```

I'm using the floating label, second from the top [@here](https://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/#input)

Can someone tell me whats wrong, or how I can fix it?

Here is an image with the problem:

[image: here is an image with the problem]

Comment: I tried on Material Design  web page that you provied and works perfectly `$('#firstInput').val("Custom text");`

Comment: read this thread:https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design/issues/117

Comment: updated with an image of the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap material design- floating labels are not floated when data is loaded dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28688781/bootstrap-material-design-floating-labels-are-not-floated-when-data-is-loaded-d)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are assigning the value, in js you need to remove class `empty` from the corresponding field.

```js
$('#ConfigName').val("testersres");
$('#ConfigName1').removeClass("form-control empty");
$('#ConfigName1').addClass("form-control");
$('#ConfigName1').val("testersres");
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.header-panel {
  background-color: #009587;
  height: 144px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}
.header-panel div {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
.header-panel h1 {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 35px;
}
.menu {
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu,
.menu * {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.menu ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 7px 0;
}
.menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 50px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.menu ul li.active {
  background-color: #dedede;
  position: relative;
}
.menu ul li a {
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-decoration: none;
}
.pages {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 4;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
.pages > div {
  padding: 0 5px;
  padding-top: 64px;
}
.pages .header {
  color: rgb(82, 101, 162);
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  letter-spacing: 1.20000004768372px;
}
.page {
  transform: translateY(1080px);
  transition: transform 0 linear;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.page.active {
  transform: translateY(0px);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
#opensource {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.62);
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  z-index: 100;
}
#source-modal h4 {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/dist/css/material-fullpalette.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design/master/dist/js/ripples.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design/master/dist/js/material.js"></script>
<input id="ConfigName" class="form-control floating-label" placeholder="Name" type="text">
<br>
<div class="form-control-wrapper">
  <input type="text" class="form-control empty" id="ConfigName1">
  <div class="floating-label">floating label</div><span class="material-input"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: @Carsten Andersen try the above answer.

Comment: Instead of messing with the classes just trigger a change event like `('#ConfigName1').trigger("change");`